# Unable to Configure Laravel Project on Live Apache Server

Tags: php, apache, laravel, configuration, shared-hosting

Unable to Configure Laravel Project on the Live Apache Server. Here is the version of Apache Server on shared hosting:

> Server:Apache/2.4.18

You can view more details by visiting:

> www.pawras.com

Go to the inspect element, and then in the network tab. There you can get detailed information.

[image]

Project is successfully running on the Local Server having Apache Version:

> Server:Apache/2.4.17

And I am not sure how to configure the **.env** when uploading the project on the live server. Or whether to edit the **.htaccess** file. Lots of confusion and I have already tried various solutions, but got no success.

Someone told me to ask my Hosting Service Provider to update the Apache Server. But I don't know what to do. Whether to ask for the Apache Server Update or to configure multiple file according to the live server.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first of all check whether the path to public folder is readable by others.

Secondly I suggest checking out [this page](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost) as it covers everything you need to set up Apache.

Comment: Here the is the Directory on cPanel. All project files are inside the public_html folder.

(/home/pawras) <br>
.cagefs <br>
.cl.selector <br>
.cpanel <br>
.cphorde <br>
.htpasswds <br>
.trash <br>
etc <br>
laravel <br>
logs <br>
mail <br>
public_ftp <br>
public_html //Project Files inside <br>
tmp

Comment: You're using a shared hosting? The doc root points to /home/pawras/public_html whereas the laravel index file is in /home/pawras/public_html/public. You have to check www.pawras.com/public and I think there's another issue with you system. Perhaps the PHP version is too old.

Comment: How to update the Php version on the server? @Mihkel Allorg

Comment: somewhere in the cpanel, perhaps this can help you: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/getting-started-cpanel/how-to-view-your-php-version-in-cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your folder setup properly, I'm guessing its because you are on a shared host.

Did you restructure the laravel folder? If so have you updated your paths.php.

See the solution in this thread.
http://laravel.io/forum/03-06-2015-how-to-setup-laravel-5-in-shared-hosting

Answer (score 0):

make sure you gave the sufficient permission to public, storage and bootstrap folder .